# Summation of iid random variables and the resulting sample space

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, independence

I am getting confused when it comes to summing iid random variables. Suppose we have $X_1$ and $X_2$ iid random variables where $X_i : \Omega = ${$heads, tails$}$ \to ${$-1,1$} and $X_i(heads) = 1$, $X_i(tails) = -1$, and each have equal probability. Now if we consider $Y = X_1 + X_2$, do we have that $Y$ is defined on $\Omega  \times \Omega$, because if it was just defined on $\Omega $  then surely we would obtain theses incorrect results: if we have that $\omega = heads$ then,  $$Y(\omega) = X_1(\omega) + X_2(\omega) = 2$$, and if $\omega= tails$ then, $$ Y(\omega) = X_1(\omega) + X_2(\omega) = -2$$

Now if we say that Y has the domain $\Omega  \times \Omega$, then how can a simple symmetric random walk be a martingale since each term in the sequence will be defined on a different sample space, and for a martingale, we require the sequence of random variables are defined on the same sample space.

Comment: Here your $\Omega$ consists of the outcomes of $X$. But usually that is the point of whole probabity theory that $\Omega$ is unkown, since you cannot foretell the exact outcome of a coin toss.  If both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are rv's on the same $\Omega$ then so is $Y$. In this particular case $\Omega =\{\omega: X(\omega)=1\} \cup \{\omega : X(\omega)=-1\}$. But also $\Omega=\bigcup_{i,j\in\{-1,1\}}\{X_1=i\} \cup \{X_2=j\}= \bigcup_{i\in\{-2,0,2\}} \{Y=i\}$

Comment: From the first identity including $\Omega$ and $X$ the sample space has two elements, but in the second identity, we have 4 elements, so how can they be equal?